# How to view data by searching data in database (BY DATE)

Tags: android, xml

I am doing a edit button.

In my xml, there will be a edit text(dateEdit), followed by a button(updateBTN).

the edit text have a code `android:inputType="date"` , so when I key in a specific date and click submit, it will go to next page(I've done up) and grab the data from the database for the specific date and display it on my another xml(update.xml).

I would like to ask, how can I do so?
It's my first attempt on date and I've no idea how to do it.

I've not done up any source code,
would like to seek advices on how I can do it.
Is there any references?

Answer (score 0):

use DATETIME as the data type for the date in your database, and then use where and like clause or any other logical operator to fetch the data from database.